# Real time plotting using mayavi

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, mayavi

I wrote a programme to plot points in a 3d environment where the data is updated using a loop. But in the loop, the whole array is plotted again and again. Since I want to add over 1000 points it will be a burden for the pc. can anyone suggest a method to plot individual points real-time without plotting the array all over again but gets the same output as this programme, Thank you.

```
import serial
from time import time,sleep
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
from random import*

rebound=[]

xs=[]
ys=[]
zs=[]

@mlab.animate(delay=100)
def anim():
    i=0
    while True:
        x= randint(0,1024)
        y= randint(0,1024)
        z= randint(0,1024)
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)
        zs.append(z)
        plt = mlab.points3d(xs,ys,zs)
        yield

anim()
```